# using variable inside formulaR1C1 for offseting

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following line of code:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sqrt(RC[-1])"
```

Now instead of -1, I want to use a variable, say x, as follows:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sqrt(RC[x])"
```

This returns an error. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Is there an error-message you can provide?

Answer (score 9):

Like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sqrt(RC[" & x & "])"
```

Comment: A related query, Instead of  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sqrt(B3)" I want to use variable x such as  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sqrt(Bx)" How can I do this??? I have tried ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sqrt("B" & " & x & ")". It didnt work

Comment: @user2812791 It doesn't work because you're assigning to `FormulaR1C1` but your formula isn't in R1C1 format.

Comment: Gotcha... Thanks... Worked like this: ActiveCell.Formula = "=sqrt(B" & x & ")"

Comment: @user2812791 Glad to know it worked out.  Now is when you UpVote the answers that were helpful and Accept the answer that you used.

Comment: so for formula r1c1, what is the advantage of using this instead of directing it towards a cell in the normal way? Is this purely just a performance issue?

Comment: @DougCoats `.FormulaR1C1=` just uses the Excel R1C1 cell-addressing format instead of the usual (Lotus-123) A1 format used by `.Formula=`. R1C1 is more verbose, (and may feel less natural) but actually slightly more powerful addressing method.  In particular, many programmers find it easier to use from VBA and other code.

Answer (score 0):

Already RBarryYoung given the right solution

May be you could try the below code

Tested

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim X As Integer
    X = 1

    Range("C1").Value = Sqr(Range("B" & X).Value)

End Sub
```

Change the code as per your needs

Comment: I prefer to put the formula in the cell instead of the value... thanks anyways satish..

Answer (score 0):

You most likely don't need to loop here, Are you aware that you can do stuff like this?

```
Range("A1:A10").Formula = "=SQRT(B1)"
```

Excel will increment the ref per row.

Answer (score 0):

Extending this question: What I want to do is self explanatory:

```
Dim  max1, sig1 As Integer

max1 = Range("B5")
sig1 = Range("I5")
Range("B9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(LINEST((R1C[" & sig1 & "]:R1C[" & max1 & "]),),1)"
```

Fails on last line as it interprets this as: INDEX(LINEST((R4C:R4C),),1)
Works fine if I tell it where these cells I want to fit as in:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(LINEST((R1C2:R1C1793),),1)"
```

Have confirmed that max1 = 1793, sig1 = 1009, and Row 1 contains 4096 integers.