# using variable inside SUMPRODUCT formulaR1C1 for offseting

Tags: excel-formula, vbscript

My situation seems to be similar to this one, but net quite exactly the same as I need to use the offset as a variable inside 2 formulas
[using variable inside formulaR1C1 for offseting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992234/using-variable-inside-formular1c1-for-offseting)

Here's something that **works** :

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(R[-188]C[-16]:R[-1]C[-16])=R[5]C[-15])*(R[-188]C:R[-1]C))"
```

Though, I need to use the Row as a variable **v_LastRow** and this **doesn't work** as I get an execution error 1004 and not sure why

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(R[-v_LastRow]C[-16]:R[-1]C[-16])=R[5]C[-15])*(R[-v_LastRow]C:R[-1]C))"
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You must build the formula with the *value* of your variable

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(R[-" & v_LastRow & "]C[-16]:R[-1]C[-16])=R[5]C[-15])*(R[-" & v_LastRow & "]C:R[-1]C))"`

Comment: Awesome  !  it works perfectly, thanks so much

Comment: Please accept the answer so that other helpers can see the question is "closed"